# How to send data into span instead of input using this.$emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With VueJS current I am calculating my data and passing it through my HTML and use it there but the only way for now I know is this for example:

```
this.$emit('input', this.finalPrice)
```

And in my HTML like this:

```
<input type="number" v-model="finalPrice" disabled />
```

Now I want to know if it is possible to send data into a `<span>` or `<div>` or anything instead of input I tried to change the `<input>` name to  and use the v-model for span but no luck with it.

Comment: This isn't enough information. Can you provide your component? Vue allows you to template using `{{ variable }}`. It injects into the rendered markup, which may be what you're looking for, but with the information you've provided it's hard to tell.

Comment: `<span>{{ finalPrice }}</span>`